# Calling server side function from signalR in Android

Tags: javascript, android, signalr

SignalR connected in Android, But I want to call a function which is available on server,

I tried the following code,

```
String host = "Host URL";
    HubConnection hubConnection = new HubConnection(host, "", false, new Logger() {
        @Override
        public void log(String message, LogLevel level) {
            System.out.println("message - " + message);
        }


    });

    hubProxy = hubConnection.createHubProxy("Task");
    SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = hubConnection.start().done(addSession("Session ID"));
```

And

```
private Action<Void> addSession(String sessionID) {
    //hubProxy. [server is not available here]
}
```

In javascript, I tried like following,

```
 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
      addSession(sessionId)
 });

 function addSession(sessionId) {
       proxy.server.addSession(sessionId)
            .done(function () {
                  isHubConnected = true;
             }
       );
 }
```

In javascript this works perfectly, But in android :( ,

**Update**

By trying like @AnikIslamAbhi's answer,

```
signalRFuture = hubConnection.start().done(addSession("sessionID"));

private Action<Void> addSession(String sessionID) {
    System.out.println("addSession : " + sessionID);
    hubProxy.invoke("addSession", sessionID);
    return null;
}
```

I received following error message,

```
InvalidStateException: The operation is not allowed in the 'Connecting' state
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you are using Auto proxy.

But in android you are using manual proxy

Both have differences in their behavior.

Like

To call serverside method using auto proxy

```
proxy.server.addSession(sessionId)
```

To call serverside method using manual proxy

```
proxy.invoke("addSession", sessionId)
```

You can find more on this [link](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server)

Comment: Okay, I think this will work, But when I invoke it, I have received following error message. `InvalidStateException: The operation is not allowed in the 'Connecting' state`. Can you guess, what is the problem here?

Comment: hubProxy.invoke("addSession", sessionID).done(new Action<Void>() {

                @Override
                public void run(Void obj) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("SENT!");
                }
            }) add this and then tell me what happens

Comment: // Subscribe to the connected event
        hubConnection .connected(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("CONNECTED");
            }
        }); check connection is sucesssfull or not

Comment: This is not connected bro and also didn't sent.

Comment: I have added logcat message there.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi I am having issues with connection and function calling. Do you have any link that could be helpful for beginners?

Comment: @droid_dev which languages are you using ?

Comment: @AnikIslamABhi Android/iOS